# How to create a Stripe object from JSON?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stripe-payments

I'm saving Stripe webhooks in the database as `JSON` for processing using a background python robot. When the python robot comes along though, this data is in python and not an instance of a `stripe_object`. How do I convert the JSON into a stripe_object?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your JSON conforms to the expected format you can do the following:

```
import json
from stripe.util import convert_to_stripe_object

data = json.loads(json_string)
stripe_obj = convert_to_stripe_object(data)
```

I don't know if the solution works in Python > 2.7

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can do it like this using the [stripe gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/b87cfbec980f4b83f4e431686d11fe7e2efcdd4e/lib/stripe/util.rb#L111):

```rb
data = JSON(json_string)

Stripe::Util.convert_to_stripe_object(data)
```